# Spark IntArrayParm in JAVA

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to test a number of multilayer perception network architectures. So, I am training a model via  a crossvalidation using different params. However, I fail to set up layer param using JAVA. Not sure how this is done, but none of the following work:

```
int[] layers1 = new int[]{10,1,3,2};
IntArrayParam p = new IntArrayParam(null, "name", "doc");
p.w(layers1);
int[] layers2 = new int[]{10,1,3,2};
IntArrayParam p2 = new IntArrayParam(null, "name", "doc");
p2.w(layers2);
builder.addGrid(mlpc.layers(), JavaConverters.asScalaIterableConverter(Arrays.asList(p,1)).asScala());
```

Sending a list of arrays (or a multidimensional array):

```
builder.addGrid(mlpc.layers(), JavaConverters.asScalaIterableConverter(Arrays.asList(1,2,2), Arrays.asList(1,2,2)).asScala());
```

I am not sure how this i suppose to be done in JAVA, and was not able to find any examples. Any ideas appreciated.

Best,
Ilija

Answer (score 1):

After some research got it, just in case anyone gets stuck using **IntArrayParam** on Java here is an example:

```
//build network parameters grid
int[] layers1=new int[]{17,8,4,26};
int[] layers2=new int[]{17,12,8,26};
//use scala collections converters to get a Scala Iterable of Int[]
scala.collection.Iterable<int[]> iter= JavaConverters.iterableAsScalaIterableConverter(Arrays.asList(layers1, layers2)).asScala();
```

Hope that helps!